# Keep listing on website based on end_date

Tags: php, mysql

I have a website that lists events going on in town. I have it programmed to only show events in the mySQL database from: NOW(). If some events are longer than 24 hours, it is not showing them. It removes them after midnight of the first date.

Here is my code:

```
SELECT *
FROM events
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(sort_date, '%Y-%m-%d') >= Date_Format(Now(), '%Y-%m-%d')
    AND DATE_FORMAT(end_date, '%Y-%m-%d') >= Date_Format(Now(), '%Y-%m-%d')
    AND authorize = 1
ORDER BY sort_date ASC ";
```

Appreciate any help in changing them to only show events from NOW(), but not remove them until end_date.

Thanks

Comment: So why don't you just drop first condition?

Comment: all of that `date_format` business is useless. You're taking native dates, converting to strings, and then comparing those strings. why not just `DATE(sort_date) > CUR_DATE()`? The string conversion makes it impossible to use any indexes you might have on those fields.

Comment: The problem is, how do I test it to know if it works correctly? I won't know until tomorrow if anything that is supposed to still be there, is there. :)

Comment: @user2930069 Replace `Date_Format(Now(), '%Y-%m-%d')` with tomorrow date to test...